# any difference between these two dealloc methods?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, dealloc

So i'm overriding dealloc method because the object is a composite object made up of one other object.

I originally had this dealloc method:

```
-(id) dealloc; // Override to release the Rectangle object’s memory 
{
    [rect release];
    [super dealloc];
    return self;
}
```

After looking in the book I saw another answer:

```
{
   [rect release];
   return [super dealloc];
}
```

just wondering if both work equally.

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: now that i actually ran the program with the ladder method, it's telling me that i'm not ignoring the void value from the last line as i should be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're both wrong.  `dealloc` returns `void`, not `id`:

```
- (void) dealloc {
  [rect release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just checked the [NSObject reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html): `dealloc` has not return type. So, I think it is incorrect to define such a signature. Thus, call to `dealloc` should not expect a return value.

Unless you are not subclassing `NSObject`...

Comment: Even if you are subclassing NSObject, -dealloc absolutely should not return a value (as Objective-C does not support co-variant types).